# Push Notification for Android and iOS using ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification

Can anyone please help to guide on the implementation of pushNotification on cross platform (Android and ios ) using React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Use following library to implement push notification. https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification. Also there are more library available to implement push notification.

Comment: One more link to implement push notification. https://medium.com/differential/how-to-setup-push-notifications-in-react-native-ios-android-30ea0131355e

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo for your react-native project this is a quite good starting point.
https://snack.expo.io/ry526Qu3e
They also have a larger guide at this link [Push Notifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications.html)